# Oracle DBMS - Manage concurrency between transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a stored procedure which fires whenever a new user enrolls on my system - upon enrolling a message is forwarded prompting them to change there password on my `AFTER` trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_users_after
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
-- Alert a user that they need to change their password
IF :NEW.pass_changed = 0 THEN
    send_message(:NEW.user_id, null, 'ALERT','Thank-you for registering, please change your password for security reasons!', null);
    updateChanged(:NEW.user_id);
END IF;
END;
```

Currently I am having a problem where both methods are trying to acquire the lock to commit their process, which results in a deadlock - I understand why this happens, but how would I go about managing concurrency in Oracle to ensure that `send_message()` finishes its transaction before `updateChanged()` is fired?

Send Message:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_message( 
   to_user      users.user_id%TYPE, 
   from_user    users.user_id%TYPE,
   msg_type     STRING,
   this_message STRING,
   request_id   requests.requests_id%TYPE
)
AS
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO messages 
   VALUES('', to_user, from_user, msg_type, this_message, '', '', request_id);
   COMMIT;
END send_message;
```

Update Changed:

```
-- UPDATES THE PASSWORD CHANGED FIELD TO 2
-- @param - the user we need to update
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateChanged(
   this_user    users.user_id%TYPE
)
   AS
   pragma autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
   UPDATE users
   SET pass_changed = 2 WHERE user_id = this_user;  
   COMMIT;
END updateChanged;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - 
Alex.

Comment: Why would either of these procedures be defined as autonomous transactions?  Why do you want to send a message or update the `users` table if the triggering statement is rolled back (either via an explicit `rollback` from your application or automatically by Oracle to ensure write consistency)?  If you're using autonomous transactions for anything other than writing to a log table, you're almost certainly doing something wrong.  `updateChanged` won't be able to see the newly inserted row if it fires as part of an `insert`.  And your explanation of what is causing a deadlock doesn't make sense.

Comment: A process doesn't need a lock to commit.  A deadlock implies that you have two different sessions each holding a lock that the other session is waiting on and that Oracle generates a deadlock trace file.  If you're still getting a deadlock once you remove the autonomous transaction bits, post the deadlock trace graph.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation - After removing the `autonomous transaction` I can see what my error was.

I always thought that the `transaction` was defined to ensure that its process finished before allowing the next to occur, looks like I was very wrong (new to Oracle)...thanks again.